# Dynamic webpage fetching data from a python script running on the background

Tags: python, html

I have a python script running cyclically on a linux and connecting via modbus tcp to an external PLC - using pymodbus. Reading and writing to the registers of the PLC work fine - as long I fetch data from external sensors.

Now I want to make a simple HTML page for showing this data (live values) and also allowing the user to enter some set points. How can I connect the existing python script with a html website?

The python looks like this:

```
from pymodbus.client.sync import ModbusTcpClient as ModbusClient
client = ModbusClient( host='192.168.0.1', port=502)

try:
    while True:
        temp1  = ReadSensor( 'sensor1' )    #function returns a temperature, works ok
        temp2  = ReadSensor( 'sensor2' )
        setpoint = ??                       #how do I fetch a given input field
                                            #from html here?

        #read holding registers 0 to 4
        rr = client.read_holding_registers(0x00,4,unit=0x00)
        print rr.registers     #This values should appear on html
        #send write command to modbus server
        address = 11
        client.write_registers(address, [temp1, temp2, setpoint])
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    pass
client.close()
```

This script starts on reboot and runs until killed. The html and the python script run on the same server.

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend using an intermediary, probably a SQLite database, that acts as your "go between" between the script that polls/writes to your PLC.

Then, have your web interface read/write from/to that database which is also read by your PLC script. You could do an AJAX call to the web interface from your HTML page to retrieve and set values.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. First tests are working good.. Anyway I have some thoughts about updating SQL DB every second (with data coming from modbus/website) on a raspberry pi. Do you think that may be an issue?